# convert jquery code to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script that i want to convert in javascript.

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {

        addCssTransform();

        $( window ).resize(function() {
            addCssTransform();
        });

        function addCssTransform() {
            var docWid = $(document).width();
            var w = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth);
            var actualWidth = w - (w - docWid);

            var zoom = actualWidth / 1280;
            var zoomRatio = zoom *100;
            console.log(zoomRatio);
            if(actualWidth > 1280) {
                $('html').css( 'font-size', + zoomRatio+ '%' ); /* IE 9 */

            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have tried and here is the output. But it is not working and giving error in console.

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 addCssTransform();

      window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
            addCssTransform();
        });

        function addCssTransform() {
            var docWid = document.body.clientWidth;
            var w = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth);
            var actualWidth = w - (w - docWid);

            var zoom = actualWidth / 1280;
            var zoomRatio = zoom *100;
            console.log(zoomRatio);
            if(actualWidth > 1280) {
                document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.fontSize = zoomRatio + '%';
                //$('html').css( 'font-size', + zoomRatio+ '%' ); /* IE 9 */

            }
        };
    </script>
```

It seems there is an error in line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.fontSize = zoomRatio + '%';
```

Comment: You should add 'DOMContentLoaded' event. Just like jQuery document ready

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.fontSize should be  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.fontSize or loop over document.querySelectorAll("*")

Comment: Is it because `getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist? I think it is. Do as mplungjan suggests.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("html")` can be written as `document.documentElement`

Comment: Try putting zoomRatio + '%' in brackets?

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like [NodeList object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an element. You can't set `style` on it. You have to loop over it and set the style on each member (which will be elements) of it in turn.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Add 'DOMContentLoaded' event
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        addCssTransform();

        // NOTE: Just reference the function. Don't create new one unless needed
        window.addEventListener('resize', addCssTransform, false);

        function addCssTransform() {
            var docWid = document.body.clientWidth;
            var w = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth);
            var actualWidth = w - (w - docWid);

            var zoom = actualWidth / 1280;
            var zoomRatio = zoom *100;
            console.log(zoomRatio);
            if(actualWidth > 1280) {

                // If you are adding styles to 'html' element, use available 'document.documentElement' property
                document.documentElement.style.fontSize = zoomRatio + '%';
                //$('html').css( 'font-size', + zoomRatio+ '%' ); /* IE 9 */

            }
        }
    }, false);
    </script>
```

- Add `DOMContentLoaded` event and place your JavaScript inside it.
- Reference the function.

You can write the below code

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
    addCssTransform();
}, false);
```

as

```
window.addEventListener('resize', addCssTransform, false);
```

- Use `document.documentElement` to access 'html' element

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an nodeList over which you would need to loop.

An alternative would be to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns a single element instead:

```
document.querySelector('html');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `addCSSTransform` function before it is defined. Move the call to after the function declaration, i.e:

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
        addCssTransform();
    });

    function addCssTransform() {
        var docWid = document.body.clientWidth;
        var w = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth);
        var actualWidth = w - (w - docWid);

        var zoom = actualWidth / 1280;
        var zoomRatio = zoom *100;
        console.log(zoomRatio);
        if(actualWidth > 1280) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.fontSize = zoomRatio + '%';
            //$('html').css( 'font-size', + zoomRatio+ '%' ); /* IE 9 */

        }
    };

    addCssTransform();
```

as suggested by Vigneswaran, you may wish to bind the call to a DOMContentLoaded event (equivalent to `$(document).ready`) as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addCssTransform);
```

The suggestions above regarding nodeLists returned from `getElementsByTagName` are also correct (the clue's in the name - getElement**s**ByTagName). There will (or should!) only ever be one `html` element, so you can safely replace `document.getElementsByTagName("html").style` with `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style`